# method ComponentDidMount - adding markers to the map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to add a marker to the map using the form. Can anyone help me? Installing the map works. I want to display markers after entering x and y, and read this data from the table. I have 2 inputs, one for X and the other for Y after clicking "add" I add this data to the table and I have 2 objects, etc ... but only one marker from state.items is displayed on the map, although I have more coordinates in the table.I know that the componentDidMount () method is only run once and here is the problem.Please Help

```
state={
items:[{
      "X": 13.6155611,
      "Y": 51.0331258
    },
    ],
}

 addItem = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newItem = {
      "Y": parseFloat(this.state.X),
      "X": parseFloat(this.state.Y),
    };
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      items: [...prevState.items, newItem]
    }));

  }
componentDidMount() {
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: this.mapContainer,
      center: [this.state.lng, this.state.lat],
      zoom: this.state.zoom,
    });
for (var i = 0; i < this.state.items.length; i++) {
      var obj = this.state.items[i];
      let myLatlng = new mapboxgl.LngLat(obj.X, obj.Y);
      new mapboxgl.Marker()
        .setLngLat(myLatlng)
        .addTo(map);
    }

}

 render() {
    return (
        <div ref={el => this.mapContainer = el} />

<form onSubmit={this.addItem}>
 <input
              type="number"
              value={this.state.X}
              onChange={e => this.setState({
                X: e.target.value
              })}
            />
            <input
              value={this.state.Y}
              onChange={e => this.setState({
                Y: e.target.value
              })}
            />
</Form>
)}
```

Comment: Can you move your for loop to a different function and call this function both in ```componentDidMount``` and in ```addItem```?

Comment: no because map would not be defined as its scope is only inside ComponentDidMount

Comment: try initialize your map in class, not in componentDidMount, then call this function both, as the man said above :)

Comment: More details please. Should I initialize the map in state? state = {map: new mapboxgl.Map({ container: this.mapContainer, style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11', center: [this.state.lng, this.state.lat], zoom: this.state.zoom, })} ? 
I really don't understand what to do